# Can't call a function on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a form using BootForm on Laravel. This is the content of the function in the PostsController.

```
 public function update($id,$request)
{
    //
    $post =findOrFail($id);
    $post->update($request->all());
    redirect(route('news'));
}
```

The view is the following code:

```
    @extends ('layouts.app')

@section ('content')

    <h1>Edit</h1>

    {!! BootForm::openHorizontal (['url' => 'user', 'sm' => [2, 5], 'lg' => [2, 5], 'method'=> 'put']) !!}

    {!! BootForm::text('Titre', $post->title) !!}

    {!! BootForm::text('Slug', $post->slug) !!}

    {!! BootForm::textarea('Contenu', $post->content) !!}

    <p> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{route('news.update', $post) }}">Editer</a></p>

    {!! BootForm::close() !!}

@stop
```

Also there is the route I'm using this one :

```
Route::resource('news', 'PostsController');
```

So, when I click on the button, it redirects me on main directory (localhost:8000). The function in the controller is not called. 
No change in the post is noticed though. 
The problem is in the update function. Do I miss something on it? 
Some tips or help will be welcome.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: just updated it

Comment: What is the value of action attribute of you form. Can you show you form here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your function with

```
public function update($id)
{
  $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

  $post->update(request()->all());

  return redirect(route('news.index'));
}
```

and please replace your view with this.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  <h1>Edit</h1>

  <?php $formOptions = [
    'url' => 'user',
    'sm' => [2, 5],
    'lg' => [2, 5],
    'method'=> 'put'
  ]; ?>

  {!! BootForm::openHorizontal($formOptions)->action(route('news.update', $post)) !!}
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  {!! BootForm::text('Titre', $post->title) !!}
  {!! BootForm::text('Slug', $post->slug) !!}
  {!! BootForm::textarea('Contenu', $post->content) !!}
  {!! BootForm::submit('Editer') !!}
  {!! BootForm::close() !!}

@stop
```

I am not sure what `url` does in the options, but I have still added it since you have also... And instead of using `<a href="....">...</a>`, I am using `{!! BootForm::submit() !!}`

Let me know if you face any other issues.

Comment: Don't you have to `return` the redirection in the `update` function?

Comment: Thanks! It looks really better because now I have an error when I click on the update button : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218: You can check my routes on the main post!

Comment: @Sharkos Yes, that was happening because many browsers do not support put request and therefore, you'll have to add a hidden field with the name `_method` to your form. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @prateekkathal  Thanks you a lot, it routes correctly now! I just have a little issue with the findOrFail : Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\findOrFail() => Do you any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Sharkos Sry about that, made another change in the first line of the function. Please ensure you have the namespace to your model at the top of your controller... Like `use App\Post` or `use App\Models\Post`... whatever you are using.

Comment: @prateekkathal Yes sure, I didn't even notice that the Post isn't there! Thank you a lot, it works now!

Comment: @Sharkos Please consider marking this as an answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

try a named route like this one:

```
Route::resource('news' ['uses' => 'UpdatesController@news', as 'updateNews']);
```

then in the UpdatesController class, add something like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\controller;

class UpdateController extends Controller
{
    public news() {
        //your logics for updating here
    }
}
```

`http://localhost:8000/news/` should now return the desired view, if your code in `news()` is correct that is.

Comment: Actually I can see my posts on .../news. I can also see the edit form on .../news/[$id]/edit. But when I try to edit with this code, it fails (and redirect me directly to the localhost:8000).

Comment: Nothing in this code makes sense. You don't create a controller per verb, you create a controller per model and you have a huge amount of typos.